# javascript function arguments only taking int

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to store serial numbers ({{item[4]}}) into an array from a table when the table row is checked. I am using an onchange function to store it into the array. However, it seems to work only for ints. What can I do to make it work for strings?

HTML Code:

```
{% for item in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="myCheck" onchange="(countChecks({{item[4]}}))" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[4]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[5]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[6]}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var thisList = [];
function countChecks(serialNumber){
    checksCounted = (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);

    if(thisList.includes(serialNumber)){
        alert("Duplicate entry, error: " + serialNumber + ". Try again.");
        document.location.reload();
    }
    else if (!(thisList.includes(serialNumber))){
        thisList.push(serialNumber);
    }

    alert(thisList);
}
```

So, for example, when item[4] = 1234. It will be stored into the array. However, if item[4] = TX-1234, it won't be pushed into the array and the function isn't even called.

I tried making the function argument be defined as a string, but that doesn't seem to work. Please help me understand why code isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: what do you see wrong with `onchange="countChecks(foobarstring)"`  what if it was `var myVariable = foobarstring` It is the simple case that you are not quoting your strings so the engine is looking for the variables...

Comment: So you have some server-side code which is generating JavaScript, embedded in HTML, and you've narrowed the problem down to "It doesn't work".  That's [not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. See if there are error messages. Look at the JS you are generating. Test it independently. Look at the HTML you are generating with the JS embedded in it. Is it what you would expect? Is it valid HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since numbers are working, I think the parameter needs to be quoted like `countChecks('{{item[4]}}')`. if `item[4]` has a value `TX-1234`, code will look like `countChecks(TX-1234)` after server side processing.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="myCheck" onchange="(countChecks('{{item[4]}}'))" value="1"/>
```

Comment: thank you so much zmag, that was the solution! can't believe i didn't think of it